# What is the method for 2D collisions detection that most engines uses?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, collision, 2d-engine

I wan't to make my own 2D game without a game engine just for learning. I am struggeling with the collision detection. I found a lot of methods but the best one is SAT method. But the thing that i can't find is how could i do handle it in very high speeds. Okey forget about high speeds, if the object's speed is higher than the length of the other object the collision won't work. I heard about something called Continues Collision but i don't know what is this.

I thinked about doing for loops for movment so instead of this

if(!collision(first,second)) move(speed)

i would do this

for(int i = 0; i < speed; i++)
if(!collision(first,second)) move(1)

But this will be a lot of work for the cpu "just for walking"

So please if you have any method share it with me with code example. It don't to need a full code or complex code cause i cannot find any thing :)

.....................